# how to order by calculated fields on doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I have a problem, when I run the query, I need to order a value subtracted by another value:

**DQL**

```
select 
    (subquery 1) as x,
    (subquery 2) as y,
z.name as name

from z
order by (x - y);
```

But doctrine raises an alert:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 504: Error: Expected end of string, got '-', but doing this query direct to database works.

(obs) plus to it, with join I can not do it from database, but with sub I can.

Comment: comma is missing at the end of alias `y` in `SELECT` statement. Is that a typo?

Comment: oh, its my mistake, thanks

Comment: Put the (x - y) in the SELECT list, alias it and then order by the alias.